# Using a hashmap in different classes

Tags: java

I have created a hashmap in a singleton class, we will call it Class A.   I have also created a TableModel class that extends AbstractTableModel, we will call it Class B.  In Class C, I am wanting to use the values in my hashmap to populate a jtable.

My question is how do I get the hashmap to Class B?

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your code, can you post a minimal code example?  That way, we can all be sure we're talking about the same thing when we answer.

Comment: create a getHashMap method in A and then just call it in B and/or C?

Comment: "Singleton class" .. well, that could very well be problem #1 ..

Comment: You want to populate in class C but you are asking how you get the hashmap to Class B? I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Composition....

`A a = A.getInstance();`  **// I am assuming getInstance() is the method to return the Singleton reference of class A.**

`a.myHash.getKey();`    **// Call any method you want....**

`B b = new B();`        **// As B is not singleton, we can use "new"**

**Now fill the table in B with the data in HashMap**